# VS2005: Assembly '<assembly>' is incorrectly specified as a file.

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, build, assemblies, log4net

I've added a reference to the log4net assembly dll to my project.

When I build I get a warning saying:

> Warning Assembly 'Lib\log4net.dll' is
>   incorrectly specified as a file.

I look up the [help for this error on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228157(VS.80).aspx), and it says:

> This warning is generated during
>   application manifest generation when
>   the build process detects that *a file
>   reference is actually a (managed or
>   native) assembly*.

This is exactly what I'm doing; the file reference *is* an assembly. What am I being told here?

How do I add a reference to an assembly dll, while not adding a reference to an assembly dll?

Comment: Can you post the <Reference> section for the Log4Net dll from your .csproj file?

Answer (score 110):

Try setting the Build Action property of the source DLLs to None. It solved the issue for us.

Comment: We have our log4net.dll at root level in the WinForms project.  I followed your advice and set the Build Action to "None".  Then I added the file as a reference and was able to successfully build and publish the project using ClickOnce.

Comment: For those who don't from where --> Right Click the dll file --> Properties --> Select "None" from the Build Action menu.

Comment: This causes the error to go away, but it introduces a whole different problem when deploying the application - the files with build action `None` will not be deployed with the rest of the project...

Comment: @dubstylee you have to set the 'copy to output directory' to either 'Copy if newer' or 'Copy always'

Answer (score 7):

I was running into this problem myself.

This is what worked for me:

I had added an assembly as a reference and as an "Existing Resource." Deleting the file from the Solution Explorer, closing, then reopening the project worked.